# How to add additional file on local repository to existing remote repository

Tags: git, github

So I have already added a new remote and pushed a file from a local repository to the remote repository a few days back. Now, I want to push another file from another new local repository to the remote repository. How do I do that?

After initializing a new local repository for the new file, the file has been committed locally. Then, I added a remote, and tried to push the file in the local repository to the remote repository, but it was rejected.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo_name.git
git push -u origin master


error: failed to push some refs to 
'https://github.com/username/repo_name'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is 
behind 
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And so I was thinking I would have to pull the remote repository and commit changes before pushing it back to the remote repository, but another error arises.

```
!git pull origin master

From https://github.com/username/repo_name
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git init foo
cd foo
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo_name.git
```

Before push, you may have run these commands to initialize the new local repository. Then, you could have taken these commands to do the job:

```
# fetch and checkout the master from "origin" and then add the new file
git fetch origin master
git checkout -b master FETCH_HEAD
touch bar.txt
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin master
```

But you committed the file first and created a local `master`, which failed the push and the pull. To fix the problem,

```
git pull origin -r master
git push -u origin master
```

Without `-r`, the local `master` and the remote `master` cannot be merged because they are really two unrelated branches. They don't have any common commit. With `-r` or `--rebase`, they are merged in a rebase way as a linear history.

And there's another way, not as good as the above one

```
git fetch origin master
git merge FETCH_HEAD --allow-unrelated-histories
git push -u origin master
```

The 2nd solution creates an ugly history which has two root commits.

Comment: thanks! is there a better way to do it though? Such as cloning/pulling from the remote, then adding the new file, before pushing it back.